# start from end of string till special character c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

This is probably a super easy question but I can't seem to figure it out.  Do you know how to extract just the portion after the '/' in a string.  So for like the following:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\4YourSoul\Server\ReportEMailService\OrderConfirmation_SynergyWorldInc]
```

So I just want the 'OrderConfirmation_SynergyWorldInc' portion.  I got 271 entries where I gotta extract just the end portion (the all have the portions before that in all of them, if that helps).

Thanks!!

Comment: String.LastIndexOf and string.SubString

Comment: In your example, the string doesn't contain any `/` signs at all.

Comment: `string = string.SubString(LastIndexOf("\\"),string.lenght());` :)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733/327083

Comment: If you are working with the registry C# has classes for that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

## IF YOU HAVE A SINGLE ENTRY...

You need to use `LastIndexOf` with `Substring` after   a bit of trimming:

```
var s = @"[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\4YourSoul\Server\ReportEMailService\OrderConfirmation_SynergyWorldInc]";
s = s.Trim('[',']');
Console.Write(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
```

Result: `OrderConfirmation_SynergyWorldInc`

## IF YOU HAVE MULTIPLE RECORDS...

You can use a regex to extract multiple matches from a large text containing `[...]` substring:

```
[^\\\[\]]+(?=\])
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e%5c%5c%5c%5b%5c%5d%5d%2b(%3f%3d%5c%5d)&i=%5bHKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE%5cSOFTWARE%5c4YourSoul%5cServer%5cReportEMailService%5cOrderConfirmation_SynergyWorldInc%5d%0d%0a%5bSOMEENTRY%5d)

For `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\4YourSoul\Server\ReportEMailService\OrderConfirmation_SynergyWorldInc][SOMEENTRY]` string, you will then get 2 results:

[image]

The regex matches

- `[^\\\[\]]+` - 1 or more characters other than `]`, `[` and `\`
- `(?=\])` - before the end `]` character.

C#:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"[^\\\[\]]+(?=\])").OfType<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: I up voted since `Substring` and `LastIndexOf` are faster than using `Split` and the only answer to touch on the multiple entries issue.

Comment: Though if the string doesn't contain any backslashes you'd still get the open bracket, but that might not even be an issue to worry about.

Comment: You could just do `s.Trim('[', ']');` since `Trim` takes `params char[]`.

Comment: @juharr: I think there are some old habits that are difficult to overcome... Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string orderConfirmation = yourString.Split(new []{'\\\'}).Last();
```

You may also want to remove the last character if the brackets are included in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = @"[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\4YourSoul\Server\ReportEMailService\OrderConfirmation_SynergyWorldInc]";
Console.WriteLine (s.Trim(']').Split('\\').Last());
```

prints

```
OrderConfirmation_SynergyWorldInc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var key = @"[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\4YourSoul\Server\ReportEMailService\OrderConfirmation_SynergyWorldInc]";

             key = key.Replace("[", string.Empty);
             key = key.Replace("]", string.Empty);
             var splitkeys =key.Split('\\');

            if (splitkeys.Any())
            {
                string result = splitkeys.Last();
            }
```

Comment: `string.Split` never returns an empty array, so the `Any` check will always be `true`.

Comment: @juharr : Habit of checking :P

Answer (score -3):

```
string pattern = ".*\\(\w*)";
string value = "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\4YourSoul\Server\ReportEMailService\OrderConfirmation_SynergyWorldInc]"
Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
Match m = r.Match(value);
```

Comment: Make up your mind -- if you (rightfully) consider this question lacks research effort, then *don't answer it* instead of providing a poor answer that is 50% hostile to the questioner.